# How does Android implement evaluateJavascript?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, evaluatejavascript

I hope to know some implementation details of `WebView`'s `evaluateJavascript`. How does WebView execute the injected JavaScript code and return the result back to the Java part?

For example, suppose I use this API to execute `jsCode` and then receive the result in its callback as `value`.

```
 webview.evaluateJavascript(jsCode, new ValueCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
         
      }
});
```

Once the JavaScript side receives `jsCode`, how does it execute `jsCode` and return the result back to the callback of `evaluateJavascript`? The following basic steps is what I guess:

```
Step 1: Receive jsCode
Step 2: Execute jsCode (e.g., result = eval(jsCode);) (using eval() is what I guess)
Step 3: Return result (e.g., return result;), which will be received by the callback of evaluateJavascript()
```

Does anyone know the how Android implements `evaluateJavascript`? Or can you point out some sources (e.g., related Android source code) that I can study?

Comment: Did you find/see: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/android_webview/docs/java-bridge.md